# For Tauri+Vue development, can I generate Windows exe on Ubuntu dev env?

Tags: exe, tauri

I'm playing Tauri+Vue development on an Ubuntu box. I clone a small project from https://github.com/DominusKelvin/nota-web, it built out 2 files as below,
* /home/abc/nota-web/src-tauri/target/release/bundle/deb/nota_0.1.0_amd64.deb
* /home/abc/nota-web/src-tauri/target/release/bundle/appimage/nota_0.1.0_amd64.AppImage
Actually I want a windows exe file, is it possible to build out an exe file here? or do I have to do the development on a Windows machine?

Thanks & Regards,
Martin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, it's not possible yet to cross-compile a Tauri application. (Example, building a Windows artifact from a Linux machine)

The best would be to use Github Actions to build it for you.

Tauri have a [pre-built action](https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri-action), ready to use.

You can find some examples here;

- https://github.com/cloudflare/workerskv.gui/blob/master/.github/workflows/release.yml#L59
- https://github.com/Levminer/authme-lite/blob/dev/.github/workflows/release-artifacts.yml#L35